# How can I Localize objects, created in Facebook's object browser?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I using facebook object browser to create my facebook open graph objects. But i need a localized version of title and description. I found only one way to achieve this by creating two different objects. Is it possible to use locale property to to set description and title in one object? Any example of correctly filled object properties would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that it's not possible via object browser, but can be done by open graph api requests to facebook.

Comment: Владислав, привет:) Тут нет лички, поэтому пишу в коммент. Я работаю в фирме Rilisoft, мы занимаемся в том числе разработкой игр на Unity3d. Мы находимся в Ростове-на-Дону. Одна из наших игр http://pixelgun3d.com. Если Вам может быть интересна работа у нас, пишите мне на эл. почту bodnarpТУТСОБАКАyandex.ru. Я программер, не рекрутер, сейчас занимаюсь фейсбуком, стал смотреть Ваш профиль на предмет связанных с ним постов, увидел что Вы тоже из России, и недалеко от нас, поэтому решил написать. Всего наилучшего:)